# Подключение внешнего устройства к wifi роутеру с помощью смартфона

Tags: java, android, wifi, esp32

Доброго времени суток.

Ситуация такая: есть [модуль ESP32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32), есть приложение на Java под андроид. Необходимо подключить ESP к роутеру (планируется использовать как модуль умного дома), но зашить в прошивку данные не получится - продукт коммерческий, и соответственно SSID и паролей сетей знать я не могу.
Изначально устройство раздаёт сеть, смартфон к ней подключается, открывает защищённый сокет иии...

Вот и не знаю, как поступить. Насколько я понимаю, устройства умного дома подключаются к wifi посредством передачи с телефона неких данных, не содержащих сам логин и пароль, позволяющих осуществить подключение. Найти такой способ я пока не смог. Также я понимаю, что логин и пароль мне андроид так просто не отдаст, максимум на что я могу рассчитывать - QR код для подключения, и то, как я понял, не везде и не всегда.

Остаётся конечно вариант просто дать юзеру ввести пароль от сети в интерфейсе приложения и отправить его ESP, но это как-то не солидно.
С сетью я работаю уже достаточно давно, а вот с такого рода подключением ещё не сталкивался.
Что подскажете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В аналогичной ситуации видел использование такого решения:

1. Модуль подключается к любому wi-fi роутеру без пароля (нужен такой роутер, который раздает гостевой беспарольный доступ)
2. Далее смарт подключается к тому же роутеру
3. Далее поскольку смарт и модуль в одной сети, то можно уже со смарта зайти в модуль и там уже в настройках прописать нужные явки/пароли

**Другой способ** заключается в использовании функции [Wifi Protected Setup - WPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup), связан с рядом ограничений, типа или наличие клавиатуры для ввода пин кода или USB токена или NFC коннекта.

**Третий способ** это т.н. режим **Access Point**, то есть модуль в начальном режиме сам начинает раздавать wifi, далее к нему происходит коннект со смартфона или ноутбука и далее уже настройка конкретных явок/паролей.

Есть и другие способы. Хороший обзор [можно прочитать тут](https://www.controlengrussia.com/internet-veshhej/wi-fi-iot/)